# Linear Alegbra - Is this linear transformation isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ linear transformation.

That : $$\dim\operatorname{Im}(T+I)=\dim\ker(3I-T)=2$$

Is $T-I$ isomorphism?

The only thing I come up with is that 3 and -1 are eigenvalues, that has geometric multiplicity of 2, and alegbraic multiplicity of 2, so T diagonalizable.

But how should I find out if it isomorphism or not? Any ideas?

Comment: I think you answered yourself, but you aren't aware of that..

Comment: If you know the eigenvalues of $T,$ what can you say about the eigenvalues of $T+I?$ If there is no a zero eigenvalue, what can you say about $T+I?$

Comment: @mfl I know if zero is not an eigenvalue then $kerT={0} \rightarrow isomorphism$, but what could I conclude about the eigenvalue of $T+I$?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then $\lambda+1$ is an eigenvalue of $T+I.$

Comment: @mfl Therefore the one eigenvalue is 4 but I'm not sure if the eigenvalue of $dimIm(T+I)$ equals to -1 or 1? the definition of eigenvalue is $Ax=\lambda x \rightarrow Ax-\lambda x=0$, but this case $Ax+\lambda x=0$

Comment: @mfl In case that -1 is an eigenvalue for $T$ then 0 is an eigenvalue for $T+I$, therefore isn't isomorphism.

Comment: Yes. But you are asked about $T-I.$ (I have made a mistake and I have written $T+I$ instead of $T-I$.) So, the eigenvalues of $T-I$ are $2$ and $-2$, both with multiplicity two. So it is an isomorphism.

Comment: @mfl Thank for your help, but I still wonder If I could conclude anything about the eigenvalue for $T+I$?

Comment: Yes. You can conclude that its eigenvalues are $0$ and $4.$ As you have said, since $0$ is an eigenvalue, it is not an isomorphism. This could be conclude from the fact that $\dim(T+I)=2.$ If it were an isomorphism it would be $\dim(T+I)=4.$